# Inf While Loop when given incorrect input

Tags: java, loops

Program overview: Ask user for phrase, ask user for an index in which a scramble will rotate the phrase until that letter at index is the first index (0) of the string. Ask for an Integer until an integer is given. After phrase is scrambled ask to scramble again. if yes, scramble to inputted index, if no, print final result end program.

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class PJ {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String phrase;
        String phraseMut;
        int index = 0;

        System.out.println("Enter your word or phrase: ");
        phrase = scan.nextLine();
        phraseMut = phrase;
        System.out.println();

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Enter an Integer: ");
            if (scan.hasNextInt()) {
                index = scan.nextInt();
                scan.nextLine();
                break;
            } else if (index > phraseMut.length()) {
                System.out.println("Error: Index is out of bounds.");
                System.out.println("Please enter an integer value.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error: Index is not Integer.");
            }
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Rotating phrase to bring index "+index+" to the front. . .");

        int count =0;
        for(int i = 0; i < index; i++){
            phraseMut = phraseMut.substring(1,phrase.length())+""+phraseMut.substring(0,1);
            count++;
            System.out.println(phraseMut);
        }
    }

}
```

Issue: The while loop is running infinitely but what I need it to do is to check if its an integer, if it is, leave the loop and continue. If it's not an integer, keep asking for input until its an integer and same with if the integer is in the index range.

Answer (score 2):

Scanner isn't actually designed for keyboard input, but you can use it for that. When you invoke `hasNextInt()`, and the next token is, say, "hello", then `hasNextInt()` does exactly what it says in its javadoc: It concludes the next token is not an int, and tells you so. **That is it**. It does **not** consume that "hello", so, if `hasNextInt()` returns `false` once, it will do so **forever**, at least, until you 'consume' the token.

Secondarily, you are expecting keyboard input to be separated out by single enter presses, but scanner isn't configured properly out of the box for that. You're badly hacking around it by invoking `scan.nextLine()` from time to time. This is bad; it means if the user ever touches the space bar (you know, the biggest key on the keyboard), all hell breaks loose as you're now out of sync on those nextlines, and it is also impossible to read blank input.

The fix for *that* is to tell the scanner you're using it for keyboard input - that you expect entries to be separated by enter keys. To do so, immediately after making the scanner, invoke `.useDelimiter("\\R")` (That's: A newline symbol, in regexp-ese). Then, never invoke `.nextLine()` - to read an entire line, invoke `.next()`. All inputs are entire lines (you hit 'enter' after entering a number just the same).

Thus:

- Call `.useDelimiter("\\R")`
- Delete all `nextLine()` calls you interject.
- If you want an actual line, use `.next()`, not `nextLine()`
- Consume the token if `hasNextInt()` returns false, by invoking `.next()` and ignoring its return value.